# Function not autofilling with current code

Tags: google-sheets

I'm attempting to set up a code for my spreadsheet to autofill information into individual cells. Each of the cells needs to be filled with a `countif` each for an individual person, problem is I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

I'm getting both:

> Error Attempted to execute copydata, but could not save.
>
> Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 3 file:
> Add code 1.gs

```
function myFunction () {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
ss.getRange("E2").setformula("=COUNTIF('Responses '!B:B,"randomemail@random.com")")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using different quotation marks. Single in this case for wrapping the formula. And setFormula with capital letter:

```
function myFunction () { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); ss.getRange("E2").setformula('=COUNTIF('Responses '!B:B,"randomemail@random.com")') }
```

Comment: Nope still giving me the same fails. Thank you though 

Error Attempted to execute copydata, but could not save.
Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 4 file: Add code 1.gs

I wonder if there is a formula that would autofill the data after the daily purge.